# can ffmpeg accommodate subpixel rendering?

Tags: ffmpeg

I've taken a small sample out of a large ffmpeg command with precisely interpolated x,y positions (only showing one `drawtext` for simplicity).

I'm having an issue with ffmpeg not accommodating subpixel movements, so the motion on my `drawtext` filters doesn't look smooth. Is there a setting that could help me out here?

```
ffmpeg -i %04d.png -filter_complex "drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:text='my string':fontsize=32:fontcolor=#333333@0:x=736.347:y=622.713:enable='eq(n\,0)'" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -s hd1080 -r 30 -crf 20 output.mp4
```

Comment: You can try drawing the text on a much larger blank transparent canvas, then downscaling and overlaying it on the image.

Comment: @Mulvya, thank you. Unfortunately, this seems like the best option at the moment.